# I want to take the max and min value of a value in a data set which with several other values in python

Tags: python

I have a dataset containing different values, `Meter Reference (float)` for the same day. I want to create a dict of a dict with date as the first key and meter reference as the second key. However, the append function returns as I get 'none' as the result.

```
readings = {}
meters_dict = {}
meter_data = []
for i in dates:
    for j in meters:
        for k in data:
            if (i == k[0]):
                if (j == k[2]):
                    meters_dict[j] = meter_data.append(k[3])
                    readings[i] = meters_dict
```

This is what I get

```
{datetime.date(2019, 4, 10): {11622: None},
 datetime.date(2019, 4, 9): {11622: None},
 datetime.date(2019, 4, 8): {11622: None},
 datetime.date(2019, 4, 6): {11622: None},
 datetime.date(2019, 4, 5): {11622: None},
 datetime.date(2019, 4, 4): {11622: None},
 datetime.date(2019, 4, 3): {11622: None},
 datetime.date(2019, 4, 1): {11622: None},
 datetime.date(2019, 3, 30): {11622: None},
 datetime.date(2019, 3, 29): {11622: None},
 datetime.date(2019, 3, 28): {11622: None},
 datetime.date(2019, 3, 27): {11622: None},
 datetime.date(2019, 3, 26): {11622: None},
```

Comment: Not sure why you are iterating over `db['Meter Reference']`, since you don't use `i`, and `max` and `min` both do their own iteration. Also not sure what the stray `if` is doing there.

Comment: You're also ignoring `j`; seems like you want a separate usage for each day, not the entire `db`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understand of your question you're looking for something like this:

```
daily_usage = []
for j in db['Date']:
    max_usage = 0
    min_usage = 100000
    for i in db['Meter Reference']:
        if (i > max_usage):
            max_usage = i
        if (i < min_usage):
            min_usage = i

    daily_usage.append( max_usage - min_usage )
```

Your `if` needs a statement next to it (such as `(i>max_usage)`), otherwise it is doing nothing.  By changing these `if` statements the `max_usage` and `min_usage` are not just the same every time and you should get more meaningful numbers.  If your `db` is not setup the way I think then this will not work, if that is the case could you provide the structure of your `db`?

Comment: This is the actual code; Meter reference is actually an object not an int

'for j in db['Date']:
    for i in db['Meter Reference']: 
        max_usage = max(db['Meter Reading'])
        min_usage = min(db['Meter Reading'])
        daily_usage = max_usage - min_usage
db['daily usage'] = daily_usage'